# JavaFX Node Variable References Overlapping in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I'm working on a JavaFX app in Netbeans, and I ran into an issue in which I created my own `Node` class for any LinkedList/Tree implementations I may have. The only issue is that the `javafx.scene` library also includes an object named Node.

I quickly realized this and changed my own Node class to have a different name with refactoring as well. The issue is that now, every time I want to reference a JavaFX Node object, I have to write it out as `javafx.scene.Node.` Even when I am just declaring/assigning a variable. I am unsure if the refactoring really cleaned everything up.

Where would this hidden reference to my custom Node object be that causes me to have to write out the entire path of the JavaFX Node object? Is there a some tool/plugin in Netbeans I can use?

I could just brute force it and copy all the code to a new project, but then I have to set up the subversion and everything again. Not a big deal. Just tedious.

Comment: Are you importing the class?

Comment: Yes I have done that. Even if I don't do it, the debugging help of Netbeans doesn't recommend me to import it like normal. I think there is a reference to the original custom Node somewhere that refactoring didn't pick up or something.

Comment: If it is underlining it yellow then yes, you are writing it out fully qualified where you reference it in your code and therefore it doesn't think you need to import it as is.

Comment: I will check it when I get home and let you know.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW: if you think there is something left of the old `Node` class, just declare a variable of this type (not using a fully qualified class name) somewhere, put your cursor on the declaration and let NetBeans navigation take you to the declaration (`CTRL+B` or `Navigate > Go to Declaration`).